# Dynamic change of IP address of ROS nodes

Tags: raspberry-pi, ip-address, ros, ubuntu-20.04

We have a touchscreen app (running on Chromium) on our RPi-based ROS robot where the user can change WiFi network or switch to access point mode. ROS_HOSTNAME is set to $(hostname).local, which is translated to the current IP address of the robot. The problem is that when the network is changed, the IP address of the robot changes. This causes the touchscreen node to lose connection with some other nodes. It seems like some nodes get the new IP address (from the new hotspot) and some retain the old IP address. The current solution is to restart the whole ROS software, but this is not ideal. Is there a way of telling all nodes to use the new IP address? Or is there some other way around this problem?

Comment: Are both the robot and remote machine running ROS? Because the robot's IP changing shouldn't matter with an IP change. There probably needs to be an intermediate communication step as ROS will default to using TCP sockets on the backend; and binding to a specific IP/port.

Comment: @BTables I am not sure I understand your comment. What remote machine? All software is running on the RPi based robot. I am not talking about a remote machine. The WiFi network is changed on the robot itself through the touchscreen app.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. So all ROS nodes are running on one machine, the RPi?

Comment: @BTables Yes, that's correct. We still want the robot to be able to communicate with other robots on the network, that's why we don't use localhost for the ROS_HOSTNAME, otherwise localhost worked fine, we didn't need to restart the robot if we used it

Comment: Ah, I see; that would be a problem. Like I said, this can really be an issue since ROS1 uses TCP sockets on the backend. How committed are you to ROS1? Because this is an issue solved by ROS2.

Comment: @BTables We are currently committed to it because we use a lot of libraries which are not ported to ROS2 yet.